# WPF ControlTrigger IsMouseOver

Tags: wpf

When I try to change image for WPF trigger 'IsMouseOver' for button, the control flickers a lot.. Is there any workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the image is already set to what you're setting it to.   If it is set to what you're setting it to then don't set it again.

Comment: I am using binding for this as below.. How can I implement your idea? Please let me know.

<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"> <Setter TargetName="img" Property="Source" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=MouseOveImage}" /> </Trigger>

Comment: I see, you could instead use the events of the objects and call back to a code behind function.  I'm not sure of the way to fix it using triggers.

Comment: Thanks, Is there any other trigger that is equivalent to IsMouseOver, I just want to change the image once when the mouse is over my button.

Comment: Checkout the events MouseEnter and MouseLeave

Comment: @BrianR.Bondy they both do not support property setters

Answer (score 1):

Use relative-binding and find the more deep ancenstor, which has to have permanent `IsMouseOver` property.